# Converting Object Data type to float data type in pandas results NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm doing a classification on the Ecoli data set as an assignment
The Data Set is collected from the UCI repository. To create a decision tree classifier I need to convert the object data types into float. While converting the data types changes into float but the string in the column changes all to 'NaN'
So that I couldn't use that column in fit() function

```
data_file = pd.read_csv('/home/root-user/Documents/ecoli.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_file)
df1_cleaned = df1.drop('SEQUENCE_NAME',axis=1)
df1_cleaned['PROTEIN_SEQUENCE'] = pd.to_numeric(df1_cleaned['PROTEIN_SEQUENCE'], errors='coerce')
cleaned_list = df1_cleaned.values.tolist()
print(df1_cleaned)
```

Then the output is like this

[data set after converting object dtype into float](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCsgE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) attempts to convert a sequence to numeric and coerces when told to do so.

- `errors = 'coerce'` will convert anything it can to `float`, and anything it can't to `NaN`s
- If you'd like to keep whatever it couldn't convert to `float` in its
  original form for debugging, do `errors = 'ignore'`

Also, can you please post the original data in PROTEIN_SEQUENCE column? Perhaps, cleaning it a bit before conversion would be helpful.